# Prepard statement already exist issue - puma incorrect config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am using rails 4 with puma as my web server. I am using postgres on heroku

I am getting error saying that prepared statement already 'a3' exist

This is my conf for puma

```
# REF https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I think my config for ActiveRecord connection is causing a problem

This might help but I don't know how to do it for puma [Postgres: prepared statement already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492059/postgres-prepared-statement-already-exists)

Answer (score 0):

The [rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1627#issuecomment-56219485) linked from the question you referred to in your question has some suggestions.

The most popular seems to be removing the `rack-timeout` gem if it is included in your Gemfile. Does sound like a guaranteed solution but has helped someone people on that thread.